# How to intercept setState function to capture individual state changes?

Tags: reactjs

I am implementing activity logging in a React application to track users activity and a practical way would be to simply log each change to the component state. The state object is large in my scenario, so I would like to capture only the changed elements, which would also be easier to read in the log. To do so it would be ideal to intercept every setState call so that I can get the specific pieces that changed in the state. I have most of all the state in a higher level component so I would have to do this only in one component basically.

I don't want to do this in every call to setState across all my component's code. I want to be able intercept it for once an for all at a component level.

Is there an elegant way of intercepting setState that does not involve creating an alternate setState function stub?

Any tips greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: pass a second argument to `setState` which is a function that fire after the state changes that way you'd ensure the logging of the state to be right after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following lifecycle methods will be showing the changes when state/props changes in a component. You can use the state object to determine the activity logging.

```
// Happens before the component update
componentWillUpdate(object nextProps, object nextState)
// Happens after the component update
componentDidUpdate(object prevProps, object prevState)
```

For example,

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if(prevState.isLoadingData !== this.state.isLoadingData) {
    writeToActivityLog('user-requested-new-data');
  }
}
```

> The state object is large in my scenario, so I would like to capture
>   only the changed elements, which would also be easier to read in the
>   log.

For this scenario, you can make use of utility library like lodash to get all the changed properties or do a deep equal between `this.state` and `prev/nextState`. Even then you may require conditions to log different events.